# how to call google api of near by placess

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, google-api

i wish to call near by places API of google maps:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=17.4359,78.3417&radius=1000&type=school&key='KEy'

when i call above link it is giving result but when i change the above link to below link

'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=latitude,longitude&type=school&key=KEY'

where `latitude=17.4359;longitude=78.3417` link is not giving near by places result array.
Can't we send latitude,longitude dynamical?

my code is:

```
let latitude=this.lat;
    let longitude= this.lng



   return this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=latitude,longitude&radius=5000&type=school&sensor=false&key=Key')
    .map(response=>response.json())
    .subscribe(data=>{
        // console.log("sucess "+JSON.stringify(data.results))
        this.schools=data.results
         console.log("school length "+this.schools.length)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can, but you need to pass variables in a correct format.
Are your lat and lon variables float?

Comment: yes.but i am not declared as float .is it any probleam

Comment: If i remember correct, it likes float. I am not sure about others, but for me it was working with float when I was sending lat and lon

Comment: but in typescript there is no float Type..see this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473489/in-typescript-what-is-the-proper-way-to-define-type-which-is-a-subset-of-the-ac

Answer (score 0):

After min 2016 your site as well as google place url need to be in ssl to get data from google map api.

make sure your site have ssl implemented and also you are calling google place api with `https`